# Web service: update on svn commit

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, svn, apache-axis

I'm developing Axis2 web service, and all source code is stored in svn repository. Web service is running on external server. Is it possible to automatically update web service every time I commit to svn? If yes, how can I do that? I use Eclipse as IDE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a few words: check out [Continuous Integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration).

You could also achieve the same goal by writing a simple shell script (scheduled by crontab) that would checkout svn and build and deploy in case there are any changes. But there are nicer options that give you much better visibility, eg. [Jenkins](http://blogs.wandisco.com/2012/01/31/polling-subversion-with-jenkins/) (aka Hudson), CruiseControl.